# How do i generate rating series in php?

Tags: floating-point, rating, series

How do i generate floating rating series in php
Like as:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
...
...
1
...
9.8 
9.9
10

for($i=10; $i<=1; $i++)
{
  echo  $i;
  $data[] =  $i/10;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)
{
    echo floatVal($i/10)."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use native [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function:

```
$range = range(0.1, 10, 0.1);
```